# Evolution triples and continuous embeddings

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I have some problems with understanding the embeddings between spaces.

Consider an evolution triple of spaces $V\subset H\subset V^*$, where $V$ is a reflexive and separable Banach space, $H$ is a separable Hilbert space, the embedding $V\subset H$ is continuous (a function $i\colon V\to H$ given by $i(x)=x$ is continuous) and $V$ is dense in $H$. **Why $V$ has to be dense in $H$?** Given $0<T<\infty$, we introduce the spaces $\mathcal{V}=L^2(0,T;V)$ and $\mathcal{W}=\{w\in \mathcal{V}\,|\, w'\in \mathcal{V}^*\}$, where the time derivative $w'$ is understood in the sense of vector-valued distributions; the dual of $\mathcal{V}$ is $\mathcal{V}^*=L^2(0,T; V^*)$. **It is known that the space $\mathcal{W}$ endowed with the graph norm $\|w\|_{\mathcal{W}}=\|w\|_{\mathcal{V}}+\|w'\|_{\mathcal{V}^*}$ is separable and reflexive Banach space - WHY?** (equivalence between norms is needed to be shown here?).

Indentifying $\mathcal{H}=L^2(0,T;V)$ with its dual (thanks to the Riesz representation theorem, I quess), we obtain the continuous embeddings $\mathcal{W}\subset \mathcal{V}\subset \mathcal{H}\subset \mathcal{V}^*$. **WHY?** Why do we need to consider separable spaces?

Comment: I have one more question: is the following implication $$V\subset H \implies H^*\subset V^*$$ correct?